# I want to know how to save the string ID and use the same to compare anywhere in any member function?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In Selenium we have a situation where we need to get the ID "MANTPLAP300920141426403767374" from an application and store it in a Object type Variable. We picked the ID using gettext() method.

We need to relogin into the application with an different user and use the ID that was saved earlier in a Object type variable in another method. We require to match the ID by doing a compare in each of the page in the approver application(some other method). 
If the match is found we need to check the box and approve the record of that ID.

Flow:
STep 1: Login as an user 1 create record and save its ID.
     2: Since its a string we Copy the ID into an Object variable.
3: logoff the application
4: Login with an diffrent user to approve the record
5: Search for the ID that was created by the first user in differnt pages if not found in the first page.

Issue is: We have one Java class where we are successfully storing the ID. After relogin into the application as a different user we are unaware how to call that object type variable and use it in that particular class.

In the debug mode we get NULL as the reference ID instead of saved ID "MANTPLAP300920141426403767374"

We want to know how to save the string ID and use the same to compare anywhere in any member function ?

CommonFunction Library.java

public static void getSourceRefId(String object,String data ) throws InterruptedException {

```
try{


    {


        ArrayList<String> NewTab = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

        driver.switchTo().window(NewTab.get(1));

        String SourceRefId=driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty(object))).getText();         


        System.out.println("the value is "+ SourceRefId);


         Log.info(" Required source ref  is present in the applicaiton"+ object);

    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException e){

    Log.error("Not able to get the source ref id--- " + e.getMessage());

      driver.close();
}
```

}

public static void searchSourceRefId(String object,String data ) throws InterruptedException{

```
try{

    WindowsUtils.tryToKillByName("chromedriver.exe");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    Log.info("Searching source ref id started");

    WebDriver driver = null;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://tpl.test.open.url.com/portal/login.do");
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("appoascgval1");
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("Password1");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Validation')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(30000);

    //Getting the pages
    List<WebElement> allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
    System.out.println(allpages.size());

    if(allpages.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("Pagination exists");
        for(int i=0; i<=allpages.size(); i++)
        {
             //allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
             List<WebElement> allrows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr")); 
             System.out.println("Total rows :" +allrows.size());

             for(int row=1; row<=allrows.size(); row++)

                 {
                    System.out.println("Total rows :" +allrows.size());
                    allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
                     String validatorSoruceRefId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td[7]")).getText();
                     System.out.println(validatorSoruceRefId);
                     System.out.println("Row loop");

                    if(validatorSoruceRefId==Constants.SourceRefId){

                      // if(validatorSoruceRefId.contains("MANTPLAP300920141426403767374")){


                        System.out.println("is it found");
                        Log.info("Source id found" );

                            break;
                         }

                       else 

                     {
                         System.out.println("Element doesn't exist");

                        // allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
                     }
        }
             System.out.println("I'm in page number" + i);

            Thread.sleep(3000);

            allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
            allpages.get(i).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Pagination doesn't exists");           


    }
}catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 


}
```

}
}

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Store the first ID as a static variable and access it again (after logging in as a second user).

Comment: if(validatorSourceRefId.equals(SourceRefId)){ 
system.out.println("found the source ref id in" + row);
}         
        Thread.sleep(50000);
        
        //clicking on Rum image button for particular row
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td[16]/a/img")).click();
        
        System.out.println("Run image clicked on at" + row);
        
        // alert accept

Comment: still not finding the first id value and compare .. please suggest to how to convert code.

Comment: `String SourceRefId=driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty(object))).getText();'

Should be 

`static String SourceRefId;
SourceRefId=driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty(object))).getText();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please:

```
static String SourceRefId;

    public static String getSourceRefId(String object,String data ) throws InterruptedException {
        try{

            ArrayList<String> NewTab = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

            driver.switchTo().window(NewTab.get(1));

            SourceRefId=driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty(object))).getText();         


            System.out.println("the value is "+ SourceRefId);


            Log.info(" Required source ref  is present in the applicaiton"+ object);

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e){

            Log.error("Not able to get the source ref id--- " + e.getMessage());

            return SourceRefId;
        }

    }

    public static void searchSourceRefId(String object,String data ) throws InterruptedException{
        try{

            WindowsUtils.tryToKillByName("chromedriver.exe");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            //Log.info("Searching source ref id started");

            WebDriver driver = null;

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();

            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            driver.get("https://tpl.test.open.url.com/portal/login.do");
            driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("appoascgval1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("Password1");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Validation')]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(30000);

            //Getting the pages
            List<WebElement> allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
            System.out.println(allpages.size());

            if(allpages.size()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Pagination exists");
                for(int i=0; i<=allpages.size(); i++)
                {
                    //allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
                    List<WebElement> allrows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr")); 
                    System.out.println("Total rows :" +allrows.size());

                    for(int row=1; row<=allrows.size(); row++)

                    {
                        System.out.println("Total rows :" +allrows.size());
                        allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
                        String validatorSoruceRefId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td[7]")).getText();
                        System.out.println(validatorSoruceRefId);
                        System.out.println("Row loop");

                        if(validatorSoruceRefId.equals(SourceRefId)){

                            // if(validatorSoruceRefId.contains("MANTPLAP300920141426403767374")){


                            System.out.println("is it found");
                            Log.info("Source id found" );

                            break;
                        }

                        else 

                        {
                            System.out.println("Element doesn't exist");

                            // allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("I'm in page number" + i);

                    Thread.sleep(3000);

                    allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
                    allpages.get(i).click();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    //System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Pagination doesn't exists");           


            }
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 


        } 
    }
```

In the above code I have made the following changes:


- Made SourceRefId as static

  Changed the return type of method "getSourceRefId" to String so that it will return the "SourceRefId".

  Lost the extra brackets inside try block of method "getSourceRefId".

  Removed driver.close() from the method "getSourceRefId" and replaced it with the "return SourceRefId" that returns the value to be compared

  And, finally changed the "if(validatorSoruceRefId==Constants.SourceRefId)" to "if(validatorSoruceRefId.equals(SourceRefId))" as Strings are compared here.

Hope this works out for you.